# Jenkins: password protect a stage

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a `Jenkinsfile` and I need to password protect a stage. The pipeline will prompt for the user to input the password and if matches the one we have under 'credentials' the stage will get executed.

I can get the input passwor using

```
def password = input message: 'Please enter the password', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'password')]
```

and when do a

```
sh 'echo $password'
```

shows the correct value however, all fails when using in conjuction with

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '9234419f-01e2-542d-b0e9-5ead17275eac', variable: 'CREDPASS')])
```

just simeple test like

```
script
{ 
  def password = input message: 'Please enter the password', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'password')]
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '9655419f-01e2-442d-b0e9-5ead17375eac', variable: 'CREDPASS')])
  {
    sh "echo ${password}"
  }
}
```

shows `null` or `****`, I also tried if `$password == $CREDPASS` to confirm but is not showing the same :(

any idea would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, whether I got your question correctly, but

```
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '9655419f-01e2-442d-b0e9-5ead17375eac', variable: 'CREDPASS')])
{
    // ...
}
```

will not store your password in `CREDPASS` within your `Jenkinsfile`, but in `env.CREDPASS`.

So instead of comparing `password == CREDPASS` (no use of `$` here), you should rather use `password == env.CREDPASS` to see, whether the two passwords match:

```
def password = input message: 'Please enter the password', parameters: [string(defaultValue: '', description: '', name: 'password')]
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '9655419f-01e2-442d-b0e9-5ead17375eac', variable: 'CREDPASS')]) {
    if (password == env.CREDPASS) {
        echo "passwords match"
    } else {
        echo "passwords do not match"
    }
}
```

Only when you want to use the variable in a shell command (e.g. with `sh`) you can access it via `$CREDPASS`, since `env.CREDPASS` will be passed to the shell command as a shell environment variable.

Besides, Jenkins will always output `****` instead of your password, since it will be hidden in your logs. So when you see a `****` you know that the `withCredentials` actually works!